# FooBar java reverse alphabet code

Tags: java

I've been trying to get this code working for the google foobar challenge, but I cannot pass two of the ten hidden test cases. The code wants you to take in a string and 'decode' it by taking the equivalent letter of the alphabet backwards and replacing it with it. This code ignores capital letters and punctuation.

```
        public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(answer("wrw blf hvv ozhg mrtsg'h vkrhlwv?"));
}

public static String answer(String s) { 

    String decode = "";
    char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
    char[] alphabet2 = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba".toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        int cint = (int)s.charAt(i);

        boolean b = Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i));
        if(b)
        {
            decode = decode + s.charAt(i);


        }

        if(!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)) && !Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)))
        {
            decode = decode + s.charAt(i);
        }
        else
        {
            if(!b)
            {
            int h = search(s.charAt(i), alphabet);
            decode = decode + alphabet2[h];
            }
        }

    }

    return decode;

    // Your code goes here.

} 
public static int search(char x, char[] y)
{
    int p = 0;
    for(int o = 0; o < y.length; o++)
    {
        if(y[o] == x)
        {
            p = o;;
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: The question says that it encodes only letters of the alphabet (actually, only lower-case letters), so what's the point of checking for digits?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not ignore digits. Right now, `abc1234def` --> `zyxzzzzwvu`, when I assume it should be `zyx1234wvu`.

Try simplifying your code. Spend some time thinking about it before jumping in. Having a mess of if statements everywhere makes things harder to understand and debug.

```
public static String answer2(String s)
{
    String decoded = "";
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String alphabet2 = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";

    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (c < 'a' || c > 'z') {
            // This is not a letter. Just repeat it verbatim.
            decoded += c;
        } else {
            // This is a letter. Flipify it.
            int pos = alphabet.indexOf(c);
            decoded += alphabet2.charAt(pos);               
        }
    }
    return decoded;
}
```

If this code fails, then it is likely that you are not describing the problem constraints completely. Perhaps some copy+paste is in order.